# Not able to resolve IP from host machine using vagrant

Tags: apache, vagrant, centos7, httpd.conf, vagrantfile

I'm trying to setup a centos/7 vagrant box. I can not get to the IP from my host machine

My vagrant file is

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"

  #vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
  #config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "virtualbox"

  ## IP to access box
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080, auto_correct: true
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "virtualbox"

end
```

When I run netstat from guest, I get this
[image]

I'm really not sure what I'm doing. I think it has something to do with my httpd config, maybe? I see this and I don't really understand why it's disabled
[image]

Not sure if this helps, but I ran this command too
[image]
Just need someone to point me in the right direction here. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own here. It turns out, I had it setup correctly but there was just an error with the website